# I got NVCC error while starting StyleFlow. Does anyone know what NVCC error is?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, nvidia, nvcc

I was trying to use StyleFlow, based on StyleGAN.

I am curruntly stuck with NVCC error, and I have no idea.

This is the error message I got:

```
        RuntimeError: NVCC returned an error. See below for full command line and output log:
        
 /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --std=c++11 -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\AA\StyleFlow\dnnlib\tflib\ops\fused_bias_act.cu" --preprocess -o 
    "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn6usvued\fused_bias_act_tmp.cu" --keep --keep-dir 
    "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn6usvued" --disable-warnings --include-path 
    "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\envs\styleflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include" --include-path 
    "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\envs\styleflow\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\include\external\protobuf_archive\src" --include-path 
    "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\envs\styleflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\com_google_absl" 
    --include-path "C:\Users\AA\anaconda3\envs\styleflow\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\include\external\eigen_archive" --compiler-bindir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft 
    Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64" 2>&1
```

++)

```
>nvcc test_nvcc.cu -o test_nvcc -run
nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
```

Even though I have the PATH:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.238105\bin\HostX64\x64
```

Which contains cl.exe.
What is happening? How can I solve this problem?